# Replacing spaces with tabs. Exercise 1-21 in "The C Programming Language"

Tags: c, strings, formatting, io

I'm looking for feedback on the code I came up with for exercise 1-21 in "The C Programming Language" by K&R.

> Write a program *entab* that replaces strings of blanks with the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing. Use the same stops as for *detab* . When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given preference?

The feedback I would mainly like is on readability, conventions and general good (or bad) practices.

This was a fun problem to solve and I think I came up with a efficient solution.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABSIZE 8
#define MAXLENGTH 80

void entab(char s[]);
int _getline(char s[], int lim);

int main()
{
    int len;
    char line[MAXLENGTH];

    while ((len = _getline(line, MAXLENGTH)) > 0)
        entab(line);
}

void entab(char s[])
{
    int i, c, nb;

    nb = 0;

    for (i = 0; (c = s[i]) != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (++nb > 1)
            {
                if (i + 1 % TABSIZE == 0)
                {
                    putchar('\t');
                    nb = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (nb > 0)
            {
                for (; nb > 0; --nb)
                    putchar('x');
            }

            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

int _getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

*The function `_getline()` was given by the book.*
*Only practices encountered in the book up until this assignment are used, I have not yet read about things like pointers and other more advanced features*

---

My own thoughts

- Use (more) comments when coding
- Use more "self-explaining" variable names
- Input longer than 80 characters isn't handled correctly

Comment: Just in case you don't know - *never* begin your own identifiers with an underscore like that.  Standard C reserves those names for the implementation's own use, so you may get a collision.  I'll let you off since K&R gave that to you (the book pre-dates the standardisation of the language, so it wasn't as certainly an issue back when it was written).

Comment: @TobySpeight This is definitely my own fault! The book gave the function with the name "getline" however I ran into issues because I think the stdio library also contains a function with that name. Coming from python I thought it was a good idea to use an underscore. I will avoid doing so from now on, thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review! I'm always glad to see someone who reads the classics.

You made some interesting observations about the program.

The statement *Use more "self-explaining" variable names* is absolutely correct: the variable name `nb` could definitely be improved. I would like to point out that *self-documenting* might be better than *self-explaining*.

If the variable and symbolic constant names are improved it may not need any additional comments.

The header file `<stdio.h>` includes a symbolic constant `BUFSIZ` that might be a better length than `80`. In some cases `BUFSIZ` **may** be the maximum line length for the system; this was true on older Unix systems.

#### Possible Bug

This code seems out of scope for the problem as it is defined, I would expect to see that it was outputing blanks.

```
            for (; blankCount > 0; --blankCount)
                putchar('x');
```

#### A Good Coding Practice

Code needs to be maintained. This may include adding additional lines to control structures such as `if` statements and loops. In C and C++ a good programming practice is to have code blocks (complex statements) in all `if`, `else` and loop statements even if it isn't currently necessary.

```
if (CONDITION)
{
    one statement
}
else
{
    one statement
}

while (CONDITION)
{
    one statement
}
```

#### Alternate Solution with Simplified Functions

It might be easier to read, write and modify `entab()` if it called a function to count all the blanks and print the necessary tabs and blanks. Programming in many cases is breaking down a problem into smaller and smaller pieces until each piece is easy to implement. While this may make the entire program a little more complex, each function is simplified.

This example uses a concept you haven't gotten to in the book yet called pointers.

```
void print_tabs_or_spaces(int tab_count, int out_value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tab_count; i++)
    {
        putchar(out_value);
    }
}

char* count_blanks_and_output_tabs_and_spaces(char *c)
{
    int blank_count = 0;

    while (*c == ' ')
    {
        ++blank_count;
        c++;
    }
    int tab_count = blank_count / TABSIZE;
    int space_count = blank_count % TABSIZE;

    print_tabs_or_spaces(tab_count, '\t');
    print_tabs_or_spaces(space_count, ' ');

    return c;
}

void entab(char str[])
{
    char *c = &str[0];    
    while(*c != '\0')
    {
        if (*c == ' ')
        {
            c = count_blanks_and_output_tabs_and_spaces(c);
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(*c);
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your observations and feedback! The reason for this loop is because when the global loop starts, we aren't sure yet whether the spaces / blanks we encounter should be tabs, in a case where multiple spaces / blanks are used, but not until the nearest tab stop, a tab shouldn't be used. example: `"hello  world"` (2 spaces) will be printed as `"helloxxworld"` where as `hello   world` (3 spaces) will be printed as `"hello\tworld"`. I did however forget to change the `'x'` to a `' '` (space).

Comment: @Ghxst I wasn't questioning why the loop was there, just the `x`. :)